# SWI-Prolog syntax for JSON

Tags: json, prolog, swi-prolog

```
json([ name='Demo term',
       created=json([day= @null, month='December', year=2007]),
       confirmed= @true,
       members=[1, 2, 3]
     ])
```

I'm staring at the swi prolog manual and don't understand bits of the syntax (https://linkedpolitics.project.cwi.nl/swish/pldoc/man?section=jsonsupport) and I can't figure out the appropriate search terms.
What does this mean? `name='Demo term',`
And this? `[day= @null`
And this? `members=[1, 2, 3]`
Are these bits of special syntax or simply weird atoms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special about this syntax really:

`json/1` is a compound term with list as only paramter.

That list has entries

- `name='Demo term'`
- `created=json([day= @null, month='December', year=2007])`
- `confirmed= @true`
- `members=[1, 2, 3]`

evidently trying to emulate a map keyword -> value:

- The keyword `name` is associated to the atom 'Demo term' (in single quotes because it contains a space and starts with uppercase
- The keyword `created` is associated with the complex compound term `json([day= @null, month='December', year=2007])`
- The keyword `confirmed` is associated with the compound term `@true`, better written `@(true)`.
- The keyword `member` is associated with the list `[1,2,3]`

Note this description at https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=jsonsupport

> The JSON constants true and false are mapped -like JPL- to @(true) and @(false).
> The JSON constant null is mapped to the Prolog term @(null)

Although one has to write

```
X='@'(true).
```

so maybe the example is foobared.

You can do this at the command line of SWI-Prolog to print the term in
canonical mode (added newlines for readability; it is my contention that write_canonical should also indent properly which it sadly does not):

```
?- write_canonical(json([ name='Demo term',
|           created=json([day= '@'(null), month='December', year=2007]),
|           confirmed= '@'(true),
|           members=[1, 2, 3]
|         ])).
json([=(name,'Demo term'),
      =(created,json(
                  [=(day,@(null)),
                   =(month,'December'),
                   =(year,2007)]
                )
       ),
      =(confirmed,@(true)),
      =(members,[1,2,3])])
true.
```